# Ocaml make a list one level more shallow (the opposite of List.singleton)

Tags: list, ocaml

I've got a function that returns an `int list list list` like this:

```
[[[1;2;3];[4;5];[]]]
```

and want it to return that list with one set of square brackets removed like this:

```
[[1;2;3];[4;5];[]]
```

The code I have so far is:

```
let rec shallow [lst] : ('a list list)  = 
    match [lst] with
    | [] -> ([]:'a list list)
    | ([]:'a list list) -> [[]]
    | [[]] -> []
    | [lst] -> lst
    | hd::tl::tl2 -> hd@tl@(shallow tl2);;
```

which gives the error {referring to the case `[lst] -> (lst:'a list list)`} 
"This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'a list list".

Comment: What about `List.concat`?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you define a function like this:

```
let f [x] = ...
```

Your function works only for lists of length 1. For any other input the function will raise an exception. The compiler will warn you about this:

```
# let f [x] = x;;
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
[]
val f : 'a list -> 'a = <fun>
```

Your actual problem is here:

```
| ([]:'a list list) -> [[]]
```

Your input is of type `'a list list list`, so this should be changed to:

```
| ([]:'a list list list) -> [[]]
```

(But you might have some more thinking to do about the exact form of the function's input and output.)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Jeffrey Scofield for giving me the hint I needed to answer this:

```
let rec shallow (lst:'a list list list) : ('a list list) = 
     match lst with
     | [] -> []
     | h::t -> h@(shallow t);;
```

Comment: If you look into the `List` module of the standard library (OCaml v4.03), you'll find the implementation of the `flatten` function: `let rec flatten = function [] -> [] | l::r -> l @ flatten r`, which is exactly your `shallow` function (except it's a bit more general). Also (as mentioned by pyon) `concat` would work, because it's defined as `let concat = flatten`.

Comment: If you define it this way, there is no need to have so many levels of `list`. `let rec shallow (lst:'a list list) : ('a list)` would be the same but more general.